# Where is db:create defined in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following command is supposed to create a new database.

> rails db:create

Where is this function defined? Or is this a pre-packaged function in rails?

Answer (score 6):

It's in the [databases.rake](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L21:L33) file of the framework:

```
namespace :create do
  task all: :load_config do
    ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.create_all
  end

  ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.for_each do |spec_name|
    desc "Create #{spec_name} database for current environment"
    task spec_name => :load_config do
      db_config = ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations.config_for_env_and_spec(Rails.env, spec_name)
      ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.create(db_config.config)
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever you doubt or want to know where a task has been defined, you can use the `rails -W` (or `rake`) command, passing the task:

```
$ rails -W db:create
rails db:create     /path/databases.rake:26:in `block in <top (required)>'
rails db:create:all /path/databases.rake:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Note it was introduced in the version 0.9 of Rake. This might or might not work depending on the versions which you're working with.

Comment: I'm working with an existing codebase. Is it defined by the user?

Comment: It is defined in `databases.rake`, but I don't understand how it knows what database to create. The user must have to supply something, no?

Comment: @asndonsadoasndo231213 `config/database.yml` usually specifies that.

Comment: Interesting, I don't see a `create` block in there.

Comment: It creates the databases present in your `database.yml`, as stated by D-side. Pay attention to `ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.create(db_config.config)`.